# Spring OAuth2 - how to use the /oauth/authenticate endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

So...I'm struggling to implement an authorization server with using Spring Boot OAuth2. For now I get a 403 response on:

`GET oauth/authorize?username=demo&password=demo&client_id=demo&response_type=token`

For the love of god, is the request okay? I would like to call this endpoint from a browser application and it should return an access_token and a refresh_token. Why do I need to provide a client_id for this? I'm on the edge of a mental breakdown because of this. How are you supposed to send a request to this endpoint?

The response is:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-09-15T05:03:17.206+0000",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "path": "/oauth/authorize"
}
```

## Edit:

My simplified question would be this: Is there an endpoint that comes with `@EnableAuthorizationServer`, and it works as I am imagining it? You provide a username and a password, and it returns an access_token and a refresh_token.

Comment: Use client credential grant or end user password grant which directly use token endpoint to obtain tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes the endpoint is POST /oauth/token
With parameters :

```
username -> YOUR_USERNAME
password -> YOUR_PASSWORD
grant_type -> password
```

The clientId and the secret must be send in the Authorization header.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

ClientId is just for user to accessing the server. so first create a server and then try to create client:

in server add this code:
`@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("ClientId")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info")
                .autoApprove(true);
    }`

Client : add you client id properly in spring property what you have kept in server
[image]